# D'Alembert Formula where PDE has only one boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve the initial boundary value problem $$u_{tt}=4u_{xx}, \ x>0,t>0$$ $$u(x,0)=\frac{x^2}{8}, \ u_t(x,0)=x, \ x\ge0$$ $$u(0,t)=t^2, \ t\ge0.$$

I used D'Alembert forula and got $$u(x,t)=\frac12\left[\frac{(x+2t)^2}{8}+\frac{(x-2t)^2}{8}\right]+\frac14\int sds$$ $$=\frac{x^2+4t^2}{8}+\frac14\left[\frac{(x+2t)^4}{128}-\frac{(x-2t)^4}{128}\right].$$ And using the boundary condition $u(0,t)=t^2$ gives me $u(0,t)=\frac{t^2}{2}$ but it is off by a factor of $2$ since $u(0,t)=t^2$.

Comment: [d'Alembert's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula) is for the infinite domain $-\infty<x<\infty$. For a **semi-infinite** domain $0<x<\infty$ which you have here, there is some work to do to adapt d'Alembert's formula, depending on whether the wavefront is ahead of or behind the characteristic line $x=ct$. This is sometimes called the method of reflections.

Comment: Your boundary conditions still appear strange. If we imagine that this wave is a string, then you have specified the initial position of the string with $u(x,0) = x^2/8$, the initial velocity of the string, with $u_{t}(x,0) = x$, *and then* you specify how the portion of the string at $x=0$ must evolve in time (with $u(0,t) = t^2$). But the evolution is governed by the PDE.

Comment: @NickThompson Nothing strange in having a boundary condition. The points $(0,t)$ are not within the domain where the PDE applies, they are on the boundary

Comment: You are right-this could situation could be visualized by having one end of the string hooked to a heavy wall which was being pulled upward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nonhomogeneous boundary conditions are complicated. It's best if you can think of a function $w$ that satisfies the PDE and the boundary condition; never mind the initial condition for the moment. Then look for the difference $v=u-w$, which satisfies a *homogeneous* boundary condition.

The fact that $t^2$ is a quadratic polynomial suggests trying a quadratic polynomial for $w$. Try $w=Ax^2+t^2$; you will find a constant $A$ such that $w$ satisfies the PDE.

Next, look for a function $v=u-w$. It satisfies the same PDE $v_{tt}=4v_{xx}$, the homogeneous boundary condition $v(0,t)=0$, and the new, adjusted initial conditions for $x>0$: 
$$v(x,0)=x^2-w(x,0), \quad v_t(x,0)=x^2-w_t(x,0)$$
In order to have $v=0$ when $x=0$, the initial condition should be reflected to become odd functions: 
$$v(x,0)=-v(-x,0),\quad v(x,0)=-v_t(-x,0),\quad x<0 $$
Now D'Alembert formula will produce $v$, and the final  answer is $u=w+v$.

---

After the comment exchange, I think I'd better work this out, following the process above: 
$$
w(x,t) = \frac{x^2}{4}+t^2
$$
The function $v=u-w$ is subject to odd-reflection boundary conditions
$$
v(x,0) = \begin{cases} -x^2/8,\quad &x\ge 0, \\ x^2/8,\quad &x\le 0 \end{cases}\qquad v_t(x,0)=x
$$
(We are lucky that $w_t\equiv 0$ and $v_t$ is already odd.) Note that $\frac14 \int_{x-2t}^{x+2t}s\,ds=xt$.  By d'Alembert, 
$$
v(x,t) = \begin{cases} \frac1{16}(-(x-2t)^2-(x+2t)^2)+xt,\quad &x\ge 2t \\
\frac1{16}((x-2t)^2-(x+2t)^2)+xt,\quad &x\le 2t \end{cases}
$$
which simplifies to 
$$
v(x,t) = \begin{cases} -x^2/8 - t^2/2 +xt, \quad &x\ge 2t \\
 xt/2,\quad &x\le 2t \end{cases}
$$
and the sum $u=v+w$ is 
$$
u(x,t) = \begin{cases}  x^2/8+t^2/2+xt, \quad &x\ge 2t \\
x^2/4+t^2+xt/2,\quad &x\le 2t \end{cases}
$$
You can check that this function satisfies all the given conditions, and is continuous across $x=2t$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation!

Comment: Raff, I am still a bit confused. I looked up the method of reflections that you mentioned and I found that $$u(x,t)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{(x+2t)^2+(x-2t)^2}{16}+\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{x-2t}^{x+2t}s~ds&\text{when}~x-2t>0\\\dfrac{(x+2t)^2-(2t-x)^2}{8}+\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{2t-x}^{x+2t}s~ds+(t-\frac x2)^2&\text{when}~x-2t<0\end{cases}.$$ Is that correct?

Comment: Did you remember to add $w(x,t)=\frac14 x^2+t^2$ to the result of d'Alembert's formula? Also, why don't you evaluate those integrals? They also give $(x\pm 2t)^2$ with some coefficients, so the whole thing simplifies. When you have an explicit answer, it's easy to check whether the boundary and initial conditions hold.

Comment: I havent added $w(x,t)$ because that method I am not sure how to do? Also, when $x-2t<0$ it does satisfy the boundary condition $u(0,t)=t^2$ but when $x-2t>0$ it doesn't satisfy $u(0,t)=t^2$.

Comment: See the expanded answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand now.